# C# Desktop App need to connect with Azure database

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, connection-string, desktop

I need some directions on how to proceed.
I want to develop a windows forms app and I need it to connect to an azure database but I don't want to have my connection string anywhere in my source code, the thing is I am new to azure and I don't even know what to search for, please give me some directions.

Thanks

Comment: Deploy a Web API to Azure App Service, and place the secrets in Connection Strings. Your forms app will call the API with a Bearer token acquired from Azure AD. See this for starters - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop/

Comment: You can put the connection string in an environment variable or in Azure Key Vault. But really, this has nothing to do with azure, it applies to many situations.

Comment: @evilSnobu thank you, after posting this here I found this article.